# Converting java file - always make parameters nullable by default

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

AS can convert java to koltin and assumes, that parameters that are not marked as `@Nullable` are not nullable, but that's not true if you have not worked with such annotations...

The problem is, that when converting file, every now and then a kotlin version is created, that forces a not nullable parameter, but this function is called from some java code passing in a null value which creates a runtime exception.

Is there any way to change this default behaviour? E.g.

```
public void funcion(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Is converted to

```
fun funcion(savedInstanceState: Bundle)
```

But should be converted to

```
fun funcion(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

I personally would prefer to clean my code manually and would like the kotlin code to be 100% compatible to the old java code, which it is only if the converter makes parameters nullable by default.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: I do not think we can override in build behaviour of convert code from Java to Kotlin.

Comment: btw, `Activity#onSaveInstanceState` is really `Bundle` because it's not nullable. The conversion is maybe correct? (overriding can't widen parameter types)

Comment: you're right, was just an example though. The issue with the state is present in `onCreate` and similar cases though... Will change the example